# Buffer Strategy for * Component

Tags: java, graphics

Is it possible to create a `BufferStrategy` instance for any other `Component` except the Windows or Frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for java.awt.Canvas

Comment: Thanks . Don't know why I didn't thought about adding canvas.